# substract day in date in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to check the date is not less than 30 days from the current date.
So i am having a condition as below:

```
date.CompareTo(new DateTime().AddDays(-30)) < 0
```

but doesn't working. cant we add a negative number to date? if not how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `new DateTime()` you need `DateTime.Now` for current date

so your check should be:

```
date.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)) < 0
```

You can also do:

```
if(date < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30))
```

EDIT: (from comment of @Rawling)

If you want to compare against the Date part of the DateTime, then you may use `DateTime.Now.Date` or `DateTime.Today` instead of `DateTime.Now` which will point to current date with `12:00AM` time

```
date.Compare(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-30)) < 0
```

Comment: NB `DateTime.Now` is current date _and time_, `DateTime.Today` is current date.

Answer (score 0):

```
date.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)) < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(No of Days)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date.CompareTo(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-30)) < 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
date < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
```

This includes time as well. If you don't want that, try:

```
date < DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
```